# my mobile emulator is no longer working in vscode

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

From one day to the next, my flutter codes no longer work in the emulator, the following error always shows me:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not update C:\Users\Yuri.gradle\caches\7.6.3\file-changes\last-build.bin

> C:\Users\Yuri.gradle\caches\7.6.3\file-changes\last-build.bin (Acesso negado)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

......................................................................................